# if I am not allowed to assign rvalues to reference why does the following snippet work, how does this work internally?

Tags: c++, syntax

I am playing around with templates and c++ syntax and I noticed that you are able to pass by reference simply by calling add(2,3) when the function is defined as below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


auto add(const int& lhs, const int& rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}

int main()
{
    cout << add(2, 3) << '\n';
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

How come doing this is illegal:

```
int& r = 3;
```

but I can call add(2,3) without a problem, aren't I doing the same in both cases, assigning a rvalue to a reference?

Comment: Try `const int &r = 3`

Comment: You are not allowed to assign rvalues to *non-const* references.

Comment: ... then check the legality of `add(int& lhs, int& rhs)` with `add(2, 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I am not allowed to assign rvalues to reference why does the following snippet work

Because you've mistaken. You *are* allowed to initialise lvalue references to const with rvalues.

> how does this work?

A temporary object is created and the reference is bound to that temporary.

Furthermore, the lifetime of the temporary object is normally until the end of the full expression, but when bound to a reference, that lifetime is extended for the lifetime of the reference. In this particular case, the reference argument doesn't have a longer life time than the full expression where the function call is, so this rule is not important.

> How come doing this is illegal:
>
> ```
> int& r = 3;
> ```

Because `r` is not a reference to const. It is a reference to non-const.

If you did change the constness of the reference, then this would be well-formed, and the rule from paragraph above would become relevant.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That would be misleading. It is possible to bind a temporary to a non-const rvalue reference, and the lifetime is extended just the same.